# Is it possible to extract data from the body of an outlook email and throw it in SQL automatically?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

**Situation**: We get audit emails every morning. The body of the email contains a table with various columns. The column labelled 'ID' is the unique key for each row. I have to copy the data from the ID column, format it in note++, and then paste it in a pre-filled query in SQL were I run it.

**Question**: Is it possible to automate this process? if so, where could I start? I would be nice if I could have something that either runs automatically or manually, reads the email, extracts the data from the column, formats it, and throws it in a query and executes.

**Additional Details**: The emails are always from the same distro, fire at the same time every day, and the table columns are static.

**My skill Level**: Beginner but resourceful and eager to learn, so please don't crucify me if I am not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can develop a VBA macro or a COM add-in if you need to distribute your solution on multiple machines. Basically you are interested in handling the [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event of the `Application` class which is fired when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`.

After retrieving the incoming item you can process it by getting property values and adding them to the SQL Db.

You may find the [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019) article helpful.